# List view edittext data loses on scrolling in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I want the listview having 2 edittexts to preserve the values even after becoming invisible after scrolling. And when the edittext losses focus, I want each edittext value to be saved in a arraylist (2 arraylist - one for quantites and one for prices), which I can later save to the database.
I tried having the code in the OntextChanegd method, but it doesn't seem right.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<String> names;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> itemPrices = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> quantities = new ArrayList<>();

CustomAdapter(ArrayList v, Context c) {
    names = v;
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return names.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    try {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
            holder.editQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            holder.editprice = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.textView.setTextSize(20);
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.ref = position;

        holder.textView.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.editQty.setHint("Quantity");
        holder.editprice.setHint("Price");
        holder.editQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        holder.editprice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });



        return convertView;
    }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        Toast.makeText(context,"!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    return convertView;
}




private class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    EditText editQty;
    EditText editprice;

    int ref;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the listeners to the `ViewHolder`

```
 private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        EditText editQty;
        EditText editprice;
        TextWatcher qtyWatcher;
        TextWatcher priceWatcher;
        int ref;
    }
```

Now in the getView() method remove the existing watches of the edittext , then update the text in the edittext and set the new text watchers.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    try {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
             holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        holder.editQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.editprice = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.textView.setTextSize(20);
        holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.ref = position;
        if (holder.qtyWatcher != null) {
            holder.editQty.removeTextChangedListener(holder.qtyWatcher);
        }
        if (holder.priceWatcher != null) {
            holder.editprice.removeTextChangedListener(holder.priceWatcher);
        }
        holder.textView.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.editQty.setHint("Quantity");
        holder.editprice.setHint("Price");
        if(position<quantities.size())
            holder.editQty.setText(quantities.get(position));
        else
            holder.editQty.setText("");
        if(position<itemPrices.size())
            holder.editprice.setText(itemPrices.get(position));
        else
          holder.editprice.setText("");
        holder.qtyWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Update the quantity
            }
        };
        holder.editQty.addTextChangedListener(holder.qtyWatcher);
        holder.priceWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Update you price
            }
        };
        holder.editprice.addTextChangedListener(holder.priceWatcher);

        return convertView;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: this would work considering the loses the that occur during the scrolling?

Comment: holder.editQty.setText(quantities.get(position));
        holder.editprice.setText(itemPrices.get(position));

crash at above code

Comment: Updated the post have a look.
Error in because i have the initilializing of the edit text. @Abhijith

Comment: crashes when i click the button that takes me to the activity which has the above adapter.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: indexoutfbounds....for this line of code,
holder.editQty.setText(quantities.get(position));
            holder.editprice.setText(itemPrices.get(position));

Comment: and if i remove the above two lines, then same exception at the textChanged methods where we r trying to write to the arraylist

Comment: Updated the answer have a look.

Comment: yes.....adds into the arraylist now, Thank you.
Consider i add the first 2 edittext  of quantity.....then if i go for the 4th one, it crashes...same with prices

Comment: could you answer to 2 more stuff please?
1)  Consider i add the first 2 edittext of quantity.....then if i go for the 4th one, it crashes...same with prices

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1


as i skipped the third input and put in the 4th.
what i did is clear to you right?

Comment: I guess you are calling  quantities.set(position,"String"); in the TextWatcher.

Comment: quantities.add(position,"  "); also fails

will  ArrayList<String> quantities = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);
  giving the size like that help?

Comment: ArrayList<String> quantities = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);
i guess it would work, try the same for price.

Comment: try this
ArrayList<String> quantities = new ArrayList<>(names.size());

Comment: did not work....
But what i did was....in the constructor...i initialised all the arraylist elements to zero for a size upto names.size();

so works now....

problem 2) After i enter the first few edittexts, and if i scroll them out of view, the clear out...its obvious why...
Is there a way to retain them there for better UX

Comment: i cant understand your question.

Comment: 1 row has 2 edittexts.
And consider i have the number of rows > no. of rows that screen can accomodate...
So if i enter the first few row's edittexts, and if i scroll down (the first few edittext becomes hidden) to add values to the further  edittexts and scroll back down, the hidden ones come back to view with edittexts being empty..(As the recycling happens)
The core functionality works...no prob,....but for users to see what they entered, can i retain then values even if its goes out of view

Comment: i had already posted that in my answer,  
 if(position<quantities.size())
            holder.editQty.setText(quantities.get(position));
        else
            holder.editQty.setText("");

Comment: you made my day tnx dude its working i tried all the solution on stack but nothing work but i would truly say you rocks @Kartheek

Answer (score 1):

You require to store update values into you data array, because list use the recycle view.

```
    holder.editQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          name.setValue(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: shouldnt i do it in after text changed method?

Comment: ok,nop. i have just set example, how to store. you do in text change method

Comment: could you please look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479562/android-view-view-android-view-view-findviewbyidint

this is what i want to do

Comment: as per question, you only require to set the data so view will be automatically change. regarding maintain edit text in list view, it is better to open dialogbox, user will enter value in it and then you can save in your data.