# While scrolling ListView randomly sets EditText value

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview which contains an edittext. I want to set quantity for each row in edittext in listview. But after scrolling the edittext value is randomly changed.
Please help me out, any answer will be appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

I have already refered to [List view edittext data loses on scrolling in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528328/android-list-view-edittext-data-loses-on-scrolling).

This is my adapter class:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements QuantityView.OnQuantityChangeListener
{
 List<String> objects;
 Context context;
 ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
 public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<String> objects) 
 {
  super(context, resource, objects);
  this.context=context;
  this.objects=objects;
 }
 static class ViewHolder
 {
  TextView txt;
  QuantityView quantityViewDefault; 
  EditText editText;
  TextWatcher qtyWatcher;
  int ref;
 }
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {

       try { 
              final ViewHolder holder;
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
              if (convertView == null) {
               holder = new ViewHolder();

          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

          holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
          holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

          convertView.setTag(holder);
          } else { 
              holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          } 
          holder.ref = position;
          if (holder.qtyWatcher != null) 
          {
              holder.editText.removeTextChangedListener(holder.qtyWatcher);
          } 

          holder.txt.setText(objects.get(position));
          holder.editText.setHint("Quantity");

          holder.qtyWatcher = new TextWatcher() 
          {
              @Override 
              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                      int count, int after) 
              {
              } 

              @Override 
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                      int before, int count) {
              } 

              @Override 
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  //Update the quantity 
              } 
          }; 
          holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(holder.qtyWatcher);


          return convertView;
      } catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
      {
          Toast.makeText(context, "!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } 
      return convertView;
 }
 @Override
 public void onQuantityChanged(int newQuantity, boolean programmatically) 
 {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Quantity: " + newQuantity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 @Override
 public void onLimitReached() 
 {
  Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Limit reached");
 }
}
```

Comment: can you post your adapter class here?

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method you only update the `EditText` by setting a new `TextWatcher` and a hint.

Not updating the text value with the quantity you update with the `TextWatcher` results in the reuse of the value the `EditText` had before. Thus changing the value in context of your data.